# Repetitious items in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to fill Listview with an array. My total items count 130. Only three different views are being created. The elements in Listview are filled like 0-1-2 and again same views 0-1-2 constant views. Because of that when you touch the element in the 0 position, it is clicked in the element in the 4th position. Any idea why is it behaving like this?

My adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements View.OnClickListener{

private ArrayList<Item> dataSet;
Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView btn;

}



public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Item> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Item dataModel = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder; 

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
         viewHolder.btn= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
         viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getText());


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.position= position;


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(@Nullable Item item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}  }
```

Comment: ListView and RecyclerView recycle items, this means the first item will also be used as the fifth when scrolling down to prevent slow view instantiations. The problem here is you probably don't reset the "clicked" state of your view. You could add a clicked state in `Item` then decide how to style the view in `getView` according to this state. Also consider switching to RecyclerView: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Thanks Nicolas Maltais. I switched to RecyclerView and it solved my problem.